# Command line terminal restaurant app errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I am working on a command line app with a restaurant theme. When the app starts a menu appears and the user is prompted to either login signup or exit. Once the user logs in or sign's up the menu appears which has a list of selections to fir the user to choose from
the issues I am having is...
1. when the user selects option 9, it does not run, it just exits the program

2. when the user selects option 2, it says command not found
3. when the user selects the option to change their account information and then when they are finished when option 5 is selected to go back to the main menu it exits the program

   ```
   def login_screen

      puts "1. Login"
      puts "2. Create account"
      puts "3. Exit"
      $selection = gets.chomp
   end

   puts "Hello there!!! Welcome to My Restaurant Eats. Please select from the following...."
   sleep(1)
   login_screen
   # selection = gets.chomp

   def show_main_menu(new_customer)
     sleep(1)
     puts "HI #{new_customer.first_last_name}, please select from the following..."
     puts "1. View all restaurants"
     puts "2. View all restaurants in your borough or city"
     puts "3. View a restaurants menus"
     puts "4. Make an order"
     puts "5. View all of your orders"
     puts "6. Add to your favorites"
     puts "7. View all of your favorites"
     puts "8. View and/or change your account information"
     puts "9. Delete account"
     puts "10. Signout"
   end

   sleep(1)

     if $selection == '1'
      sleep(1)
      puts "Enter username"
      user_name = gets.chomp
      sleep(1)
      puts "Please enter password"
      pass_word = gets.chomp
      # binding.pry
      new_customer = Customer.find_by(username: user_name)
      new_cus_pass = Customer.find_by(password: pass_word)
      # binding.pry
        if new_customer == nil
         sleep(1)
         puts "Sorry, user not found. Please try again"
         login_screen
        elsif new_customer && !new_cus_pass
          puts "Incorrect password. Please try again"
          sleep(1)
          # binding.pry
     login_screen
       else if new_customer && new_cus_pass
       sleep(1)
    show_main_menu(new_customer)
     end
   end

      elsif $selection == '2' #doesnt start
       sleep(1)
       puts "Enter your full name."
       fullname = gets.chomp
       sleep(1)


   puts "Enter your email address."
      email = gets.chomp
      sleep(1)
      puts "Enter your desired username."
      user_name = gets.chomp
      while Customer.exists?(username: user_name) do


      sleep(1)
       puts "This username is already taken. Please enter a different one"
       user_name = gets.chomp
       sleep(1)
       break if !Customer.exists?(username: user_name)
    end
       sleep(1)
       puts "Enter a password of your choice"
       pass_word = gets.chomp
       new_customer = Customer.create(first_last_name: fullname, email_address: email, 
       username: user_name,
       password: pass_word)
       sleep(1)
       show_main_menu(new_customer)


       elsif $selection == '3'
        sleep(1)
        exit(0)
     end

      # $current_user = user_name
        main_menu_selection = gets.chomp

       if main_menu_selection == '1'
       sleep(1)
       view = Restaurant.view_all_restaurants
       sleep(1)
       show_main_menu(new_customer)

       elsif main_menu_selection == '2'
         sleep(1)
         puts "Enter borough or city"
         borough_city = gets.chomp
         res_locations = Restaurant.view_res_by_location(borough_city)
         puts "The resturants in the #{borough_city} are:"
            res_locations.each do |restaurant|
              puts "#{restaurant.name}."
          end
        sleep(1)
        show_main_menu(new_customer)

        elsif main_menu_selection == '3' #says undefined method when turning it into a  
        method
          puts "For which resturant would you like to view its menu?"
          # view = Restaurant.view_all_restaurants
          res_name = gets.chomp
            find = Restaurant.find_by_name(res_name) #find contains the instance of the 
            restaurnt
              puts "The menu for #{res_name}, is as follows...."
              # binding.pry
              # find_a_menu = find.menus
               find_a_menu = find.menus.select do |menu|
                  menu.meal
               end
              find_a_menu.each_with_index do |menu, index|
                  puts "#{index + 1}. #{menu.menu_type}"
                  JSON.parse(menu.meal).each_with_index do |item|
                  puts "    #{item}"
                end
               end

               elsif main_menu_selection == '5'
                  my_orders = Order.all.each do |all_orders|
                  all_orders.customer_id == self.customer_id
                end


               elsif main_menu_selection == '6'
                  puts "What restaurant would you like to add to your favorites?"
                  fav_res = gets.chomp
                  fav = Restaurant.find_by(name: fav_res)
                  new_favorite = Favorite.create(restaurnt_id: fav.id, customer_id:   
                  new_customer.id)
                  puts "You have successfully added #{fav_res} to your favorites"

                elsif main_menu_selection == '8'
                  sleep(1)
                  puts "1. View Account Informtion"
                  puts "2. Change Account Information"
                  puts "3. Back to main menu"
                  select = gets.chomp
              if select == '1'
                 sleep(1)
                 get_info = Customer.view_customer_info(user_name)
                 get_info.each do |information|
                 # binding.pry
                 sleep(1)
                 puts "Username: #{information.username}"
                 puts "First and Last Name: #{information.first_last_name}"
                 puts "Email Address: #{information.email_address}"
             end
                 elsif select == '2'
                   while 1==1
                     sleep(1)
                      puts "1. Change Your First and Last Name"
                      puts "2. Change Your Email Address"
                      puts "3. Change Your Username"
                      puts "4. Change Your Password"
                      puts "5. Back to main menu"
                      select_another = gets.chomp
                      if select_another  == '1'
                        sleep(1)
                        puts "What would you like to change your name to?"
                        change_name = gets.chomp
                        new_customer.update_attribute(:first_last_name, change_name)
                      elsif select_another  == '2'
                        sleep(1)
                        puts "What would you like to change your email address to?"
                        change_email = gets.chomp
                        new_customer.update_attribute(:email_address, change_email)
                     elsif select_another  == '3'
                      sleep(1)
                      puts "What would you like to change your username to?"
                      change_username = gets.chomp
                      new_customer.update_attribute(:username, change_username)
                     elsif select_another  == '4'
                      sleep(1)
                      puts "What would you like your new password to be?"
                      change_password = gets.chomp
                     new_customer.update_attribute(:password, change_password)
                   elsif select_another == '5'
                    break
                    sleep(1)
                   show_main_menu(new_customer)
                 end
               end
               elsif select == '3'
                 sleep(1)
                  show_main_menu(new_customer)


              elsif main_menu_selection == '9' #doesnt run
               # sleep(1)
               Customer.destroy_all(username: user_name)
               sleep(1)
               puts "Your account has been successfuly deleted"
               sleep(1)
               login_screen
            end


               elsif main_menu_selection == '10'
                 sleep(1)
                 puts "You have been signed out"
                 sleep(1)
                login_screen
              end
   ```

Comment: Is this the entire app code?  How are you running this script?

Comment: What's with all the `sleep`s? What "command" isn't found (e.g., what's the *actual* error message)? Unrelated, but it's difficult to make heads or tails of the code because of the (seemingly) arbitrary indentation and length.

Comment: the sleep allows you to wait a certain amount of time before bringing up the next line of code. Are you using rails @DaveNewton and I can post my GitHub respiratory if that would help so you can run it on your computer and see

Comment: there aren't any actual error messages, what I mentioned are just bugs in the code, apologize for not being clear with that, and the sleep allows you to wait a certain amount of time before bringing up the next line of code @DaveNewton

Comment: I know what sleep *is* I just don't know why it's there. I don't see anything Rails-related.

Comment: @DaveNewton `Customer.find_by` is rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit hard to read, but it seems like you're doing some self-paced learning here. A few things:

- One of the most important thing virtually *every* programmer must learn and remember is *if you have to scroll in order to read an entire function or method, it's too long!* :)
- By spending some time organizing your code and abstracting it out into organized classes and methods, it makes it easier for you *and others* to understand what's going on and find bugs (ordering methods in the same logical progression as they are expected to be called is also helpful)
- The program you're writing would benefit from the use of case statements (https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/), which are also called "switch statements" in some other languages

The indentation in the code you provided is very inconsistently formatted so it's a bit hard to understand what a lot of things there do without a ton of effort, but my guess is that your issue here is once you verify there is a customer via `else if new_customer && new_cus_pass`, you proceed to call `show_main_menu(new_customer)`. If you look at your `show_main_menu` method definition, you are printing the different options to the console but you never call `gets.chomp` to read in the selection. So that should be where you're getting stuck.

As an aside, querying for `Customer.find_by(username: user_name)` AND `Customer.find_by(password: pass_word)` doesn't make a lot of sense to do because:

- A username has an expectation of being unique, but a password doesn't; more than one user may decide to use the same password
- Because more than one person may choose the same password, `new_cus_pass` will return the first customer that has that password -- not necessarily the *right* customer
- It's very inefficient to perform unnecessary database calls, so you always want to get what you need the first time around whenever possible. You can also query for multiple attributes in the same query, e.g., `Customer.find_by(username: user_name, password: pass_word)`; if the record isn't found, `find_by` will fail gracefully and return `nil`.

I took a bunch of time to go through and restructure your code into something more consistent with programming best practices:

```
def run 
  puts "Hello there!!! Welcome to My Restaurant Eats. Please select from the following...."
  process_login
end

def process_login
  case login_screen_selection 
  when '1'
    existing_user
  when '2'
    create_account
  when '3'
    exit_application
  else 
    process_login
  end
end

def login_screen_selection
  puts "1. Login"
  puts "2. Create account"
  puts "3. Exit"
  gets.chomp
end

def existing_user 
  customer = Customer.find_by(
    username: get_username, 
    password: get_password
  )
  if customer.nil? 
    customer_not_found(username)
  else
    main_menu(customer)
  end
end

def get_username
  puts 'Enter username'
  gets.chomp
end

def get_password 
  puts "Please enter password"
  gets.chomp 
end

def customer_not_found
  puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
  login_screen
end

def create_account
  # You can assign the 'get' method results to a var if you want
  customer = Customer.create(
    first_last_name: get_full_name, 
    email_address:   get_email, 
    username:        get_username,
    password:        get_password
  )
  main_menu(customer)
end

def exit_application
  exit(0)
end

def get_full_name 
  puts 'Enter your full name.'
  gets.chomp
end

def get_email 
  puts 'Enter your email address.'
  gets.chomp
end 

def get_username
  puts 'Enter your desired username.'
  username = gets.chomp 
  while Customer.exists?(username: username) do
    puts "This username is already taken. Please enter a different one"
    username = gets.chomp
    break if Customer.find_by(username: username).nil?
  end
  username
end

def get_password 
  puts "Enter a password of your choice"
  gets.chomp
end

def main_menu_selection
  puts "HI #{new_customer.first_last_name}, please select from the following..."
  puts "1. View all restaurants"
  puts "2. View all restaurants in your borough or city"
  puts "3. View a restaurants menus"
  puts "4. Make an order"
  puts "5. View all of your orders"
  puts "6. Add to your favorites"
  puts "7. View all of your favorites"
  puts "8. View and/or change your account information"
  puts "9. Delete account"
  puts "10. Signout"
  gets.chomp
end

def main_menu(customer)
  case main_menu_selection
  when '1'
    view_all_restaurants
  when '2'
    view_borough_or_city(customer)
  when '3'
    view_restaurant_menu
  when '4'
    # TODO: define this
  when '5'
    view_orders(customer)
  when '6'
    add_favorite_restaurant(customer)
  when '7'
    # TODO: define this
  when '8'
    manage_account(customer)
  when '9'
    delete_account(customer)
  when '10'
    sign_out
  end
end

def view_all_restaurants
  Restaurant.view_all_restaurants
  main_menu(customer)
end

def view_borough_or_city(customer)
  puts "Enter borough or city"
  city = gets.chomp
  puts "The resturants in the #{city} are:"
  Restaurant.view_res_by_location(city).each do |restaurant|
    puts "#{restaurant.name}."
  end
  main_menu(customer)
end

def view_restaurant_menu
  puts "For which resturant would you like to view its menu?"
  name = gets.chomp
  restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_name(name) 
  puts "The menu for #{name}, is as follows...."
  menus_with_meals = restaurant.menus.select do |menu|
    menu.meal
  end
  menus_with_meals.each_with_index do |menu, index|
    puts "#{index + 1}. #{menu.menu_type}"
    JSON.parse(menu.meal).each_with_index do |item|
    puts "    #{item}"
    end
  end
end

def view_orders(customer)
  # IMO orders should have a belongs_to association with customer
  # then you could do customer.orders
  Order.where(customer_id: customer.id)
end

def add_favorite_restaurant(customer)
  puts "What restaurant would you like to add to your favorites?"
  favorite_name = gets.chomp
  restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(name: favorite_name)
  Favorite.create(
    restaurant_id: restaurant.id, 
    customer_id:   new_customer.id
  )
  puts "You have successfully added #{favorite_name} to your favorites"
end

def manage_account(customer)
  case manage_account_selection
  when '1'
    display_customer_info(customer)
  when '2'
    update_customer_info(customer)
  when '3'
    main_menu(customer)
  end
end 

def display_customer_info(customer)
  puts "Username: #{customer.username}"
  puts "First and Last Name: #{customer.first_last_name}"
  puts "Email Address: #{customer.email_address}"
end

def manage_account_selection
  puts "1. View Account Informtion"
  puts "2. Change Account Information"
  puts "3. Back to main menu"
  gets.chomp
end

def delete_account(customer)
  # You already have a reference to the customer record, use it
  customer.destroy!
  puts 'Your account has been successfuly deleted'
  login_screen
end

def update_customer_info(customer)
  while true 
    case update_customer_info_selection
    when '1'
      update_first_last_name(customer)
    when '2'
      update_email(customer)
    when '3'
      update_username(customer)
    when '4'
      update_password(customer)
    when '5'
      main_menu(customer)
    end
  end
end

def update_customer_info_selection
  puts "1. Change Your First and Last Name"
  puts "2. Change Your Email Address"
  puts "3. Change Your Username"
  puts "4. Change Your Password"
  puts "5. Back to main menu"
  gets.chomp
end

def update_first_last_name(customer)
  puts 'What would you like to change your name to?'
  customer.update!(first_last_name: gets.chomp)
end

def update_email(customer)
  puts 'What would you like to change your email address to?'
  csutomer.update!(email_address: gets.chomp)
end

def update_username(customer)
  puts 'What would you like to change your username to?'
  customer.update!(username: gets.chomp)
end

def update_password(customer)
  puts 'What would you like your new password to be?'
  customer.update!(password: gets.chomp)
end

def sign_out
  puts "You have been signed out"
  login_screen
end

# Start the entire flow with one command!
run
```

Please take some time to look at the refactored code in detail and use it to help shape how you write code in the future. This should give you a much clearer picture of how to write structured, readable code in alignment with programming best practices. Everything is broken down into small, human readable methods, and everything is ordered in the same logical flow as you would proceed through the application. Coding in this way makes it much easier for you (and others!) to understand everything your code does and track down bugs. If you're wondering why I ended methods with `gets.chomp`, it's because Ruby methods always return the value of the last thing in the method definition (in this case, it should be the value the user typed into the console). Happy learning :)